# Passing parameters to ASCX user control in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass a string parameter to an ASCX. I want to set this to the text property of a label. In the code below it shows betwen the div tags (ignore the % signs in the html tags).

```
<@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<string>" >  
<%asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" **Text="<%# Model %> Test"** CssClass="isslabel"><%/asp:Label>  
<%div><%: Model %><%/div>
```

However in the label tag no matter what I put between the angle brackets (bit it bold) in the text tag I cannot get the parameter to appear. I have tried <%: Model %> to no avail. Is the issue that the code block is inside quotes and am I just missing some character?

Comment: Remove asp:label from your View code because ASP.NET Webforms controls do go together with ASP.NET MVC. Then follow s1mm0t steps.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to use a web forms user control with MVC?

Assuming the model is the string you want to display and you are passing this through correctly, along the lines of

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("MyUserControlView", "My String To Display"); %>
```

In your "parent" page, you will be able to do the following in your ascx:

```
<%= Html.Label(Model) %>
```

Instead of `<asp:label...`

**Update**

If you need to specify then you have a number of options, you could wrap the Html.Label call in a div and specify the class of the div (updating your css accordingly), you could use a display template, or simply explicitly use the Html like the following:

```
<label for="someIdThatICouldUseAnotherHtmlExtensionMethodToGet"><%: Model %></label>
```

The key problem with your code (as now also pointed out in the comments by @mare) is that you are trying to use a web forms control in an MVC view.

Comment: Thanks but I need to be able to specify the css class and Html.Label doesn't seem to offer that